# Use filter to filter result in angularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

[image]Hi I have a table with data in it,what I what is to filter the result so that if a table row have a datetime that is not current like today's date that specific row must not be shown or just change the background-color of it. Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work. Even if it's not filter what-else can I use? Basically the first row must appear

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-fixedheader">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>KomaxShortname</th>
            <th>OriginalFileName</th>
            <th>OriginalPath</th>
            <th>OriginalModifiedDateTime</th>
            <th>UpLoadedDateTime</th>
            <th>AgeInMinutes</th>
            <th>FileLength</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="latestwpcsfiles in Model.WpcsFiles  | filter:{OriginalModifiedDateTime:'!CurrentDateTime'}">
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.KomaxShortname}}</td>
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.OriginalFileName}}</td>
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.OriginalPath}}</td>
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.OriginalModifiedDateTime}}</td>
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.UpoadedDateTime}}</td>
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.AgeInMinutes}}</td>
            <td>{{latestwpcsfiles.FileLength}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
```

JS

```
function Model($http) {
            var self = this;
            self.$http = $http;
            self.WpcsFiles = [];

 self.GetLatestWpcsFiles = function () {      
             return ngHesto.Ajax.Get(self.$http
                   , {
                       url: 'http://10.19.13.68/GetLatestWpcsFiles/Default.aspx'
                      , success: function (data) {
                       self.WpcsFiles = data.data;
                       console.log(self.WpcsFiles);
                   }
              });
         }
         self.GetLatestWpcsFiles();
      }

  ngAppModule.controller('LatestWpcsFilesController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
         $scope.Model = new Model($http);
 }]);
```

Comment: The filter currently searches for entries which `OriginalModifiedDateTime` property's value is the string `'!CurrentDateTime'`. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Yes,okay I have about 23 records in the table around 20 records does show today's date which is fine.The other 3 records doesn't show today's date which is fine also because of certain reason they don't show today's date I want the 3 records to not appear on the table or if they appear the background color of it must change or something like that

Comment: Without knowing what is OriginalModifiedDateTime (a String?)  use !CurrentDateTime  . What is CurrentDateTime  and where it comes from? it is not in your controller?

Comment: @micha CurrentDateTime is suppose to be today's date.Like the computers CurrentDate

Comment: @micha it's like I don't want to include the date that is not today's date in the table

Comment: than use only without the ' '

Comment: I just did still it doesn't work

Comment: of course it doesnt, `!CurrentDateTime` will be `false`, remove the `!`

Comment: When I remove the ! nothing gets displayed in the table

Comment: Are you sure the dates match? By default a js date contains also hours, minutes and seconds. If you want to compare just the date, you need to call `getDate()` on the values.

Comment: @FlorianGi can you give me an example

Comment: Anyways thanks for all your help,I will and find another way to achieve the result I want

Comment: Be a little more patient, you can't expect to get an answer within 1 hour^^

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way imo would be to create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) like this:

```
function(items, date) {
    var result = [];
    if (items != null) {
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++;){
            var item = items[i];
            if (item.OriginalModifiedDateTime.getDate() == date.getDate())
                result.push(item);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```